# Console is displaying code content instead of executing it

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, console.log

I modify a function for collecting array difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)
to handle multi-dimensional array, the code is not working as expected and debugging it has been very problematic because console.log is just displaying content of the code instead of executing it...

```js
function arrDiff(xs, yx, d) {
  const apply = f => x => f(x);
  const flip = f => y => x => f(x)(y);
  const concat = y => xs => xs.concat(y);
  const createMap = xs => new Map(xs);
  const filter = f => xs => xs.filter(apply(f));

  //left difference
  const differencel = xs => yx => {
    const zs = createMap(yx);
    return filter(([k, x]) => zs.has(x) ? false : true)(xs);
  };
  if (d == 'left') return differencel
  //right difference
  const difference2 = flip(differencel);
  if (d == 'join') return difference2;

  //union
  if (d == "union") {
    const map = new Map([...xs, ...yx]);
    return map;
  }
  // symmetric difference
  const difference = yx => xs => concat(differencel(xs)(yx))
    (flip(differencel)(xs)(yx));
  return difference;
}
const xs = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 2],
  ['d', 3],
  ['e', 4],
  ['f', 5]
];
const ys = [
  ['g', 0],
  ['h', 1],
  ['f', 2],
  ['b', 3],
  ['c', 3],
  ['a', 3],
  ['e', 6],
  ['h', 7]
];
console.log(arrDiff(xs, ys, 'left'));
```

Comment: `difference` is a function. You're just returning the function, not calling it.

Comment: I don't see the point to store functions like `new Map()`, `concat()` or `filter()` inside new variables. Anyways - are you sure that you want to declare them as currying functions?

Comment: `difference` ends up getting assigned a function rather than a result, it looks like `difference1` in the end. I can't quite unravel exactly how, but partial application isn't my thing. Somewhere along the line, you've missed out calling it. Some of those are double-level partial applications at which point I lose interest. :-)